# How to change the style of an element retrieved from JS getelementbyid in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to target an element in the the DOM that has already been returned, and rendered, by another component; I was hoping to use a `getElementById()` call, and then change the CSS of that element.

Comment: I think that the "React way" to do this would be to tell the component that originally rendered the element to re-render it with the new styles

Comment: you could use a specific varibale for it and then just assign the new classname due to each conditonal;  let className = a ? "first" : "second"; then use className to reference your styles

Answer (score 2):

Its bad idea to use getElementById in React. You can use style like this

```
<div style={{ height: 10 }}>
  Hello World!
</div>
```

Or give attribute className to your element and make styles for that class in css.

```
<div className="button" />
```

Comment: "*[It's a] bad idea to use `getElementById()` in React.*" - you're right, but to improve the answer you might explain *why* :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use element.style to change css properties.

**Edit :** It seems that you shouldn't use getElementById with React.

```js
let element = document.getElementById('hi')
element.style.color = "white";
element.style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

```html
<div id="hi">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the css file add
`#h1 { font-size: '12px'; }`
and in HTML file use this
`<div id="hi"></div>`